# Setting up a Fossil server on Apache

Tags: apache, cgi, fossil

I'm trying to set up a Fossil server on an externally hosted Apache server without much luck. I created the cgi script and placed it and the executable in the cgi folder. I don't have access to any directories before the www directory which is considered as my root directory. The problem comes when I attempt to run the script as I always get an 500 internal server error response. Every folder and file has been given 755 permissions.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Here is my script which i named "repo.cgi"

```
#!/cgi/fossil
repository: /fossils/project.fossil
```

And this is the url format that gives me the error.

```
website.com/cgi/repo.cgi
```

Comment: Maybe you have solved this problem, but if not then a little more information would be useful. Placing your fossil binary in a /cgi folder is an uncommon way of doing things, and most likely revisiting your set-up is in order. Most people appear to put their fossil binary in /usr/local/lib. I myself tend to do that in /opt/fossil, but that is a matter of choice. Check where the binaries are, and check that your fossils are really in the root of your system (as you are telling your script), and not, for instance, in your home folder. The latter would be a more common approach.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you got "500 internal server error", you have possibly the following issue:

Your web server uses 64bit Linux without 32bit compatibility libraries installed.

On the other hand the official fossil binary is 32bit and compiled to dynamically link some 32bit libraries.

You can fix the problem probably by using the statically linked fossil binary. (I am assuming you can't install the needed libraries on the server).

Download the source code and try to compile it with the proper option. (IIRC "--static")